# How to remove Google Sheets Chart from Google Slide if Chart has no data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I am inserting an embedded chart from Sheets to Slides using app script. But I would like to remove the chart from the slide if on Google Sheets the chart is empty/has no data.

I want to remove the chart from slides ONLY when it doesn't have data. But keep the chart if there is data

Can you please help me add the right line that would create this condition ?

This is my chart code:

```
function onOpen() {
// Get the Ui object. 
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

// Create a custom menu. 
ui.createMenu('Present Data')
.addItem("Generate Report","generateLandingPagesReport")
.addToUi();
}

function generateLandingPagesReport() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Overall Performance 1');
var values = sheet.getRange('A2:J23').getValues(); 
var chartRegion1 = sheet.getCharts()[0];
var chartGender1 = sheet.getCharts()[1];

// Access the template presentation
var templateId = "1bXAYGCKkpZhksXz8gTCgFYbNoI1BIhAZakd68VlXHeo";
var template = SlidesApp.openById(templateId);
var templateSlides = template.getSlides();

// Create a Slides presentation, removing the default
// title slide.
var presentationTitle =
ss.getName() + " Presentation";
var slides = SlidesApp.create(presentationTitle);
var defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();
defaultSlides.forEach(function(slide) {
slide.remove()
});
var defaultSlide = defaultSlides [1]; 

// Insert slides from template
var index = 0;
templateSlides.forEach(function(slide) {
 var newSlide = slides.insertSlide(index);
 var elements = slide.getPageElements();
 elements.forEach(function(element) {
   newSlide.insertPageElement(element);
});
index++;
});

values.forEach(function(page){
if(page[0]){

var landingPage = page[0];
var sessions = page[1];
var newSessions = page[2];
var pagesPer = page[5];
var goalRate = page[7];
var goalValue = page[9];

// Insert slides from template
var index = 0;
templateSlides.forEach(function(slide) {
 var newSlide = slides.insertSlide(index);
 var elements = slide.getPageElements();
 elements.forEach(function(element) {
   newSlide.insertPageElement(element);
});
index++;
});

defaultSlides = slides.getSlides(); //update the slides array for 
indexes and length
defaultSlide = defaultSlides[1];
newSlide = defaultSlide;
newSlide2 = defaultSlides[2];

var shapes = (newSlide.getShapes());
 shapes.forEach(function(shape){
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{landing page}}',landingPage);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{sessions}}',sessions);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{new sessions}}',newSessions);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{pages per session}}',pagesPer);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{goal rate}}',goalRate);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{goal value}}',goalValue);
 })
 var shapes = (newSlide2.getShapes());
 shapes.forEach(function(shape){
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{landing page}}',landingPage);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{sessions}}',sessions);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{new sessions}}',newSessions);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{pages per session}}',pagesPer);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{goal rate}}',goalRate);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{goal value}}',goalValue);
 }); 

 presLength = defaultSlides.length; 
 newSlide.move(presLength);
 newSlide2.move(presLength); 
 defaultSlides[0].remove();
 defaultSlides[3].remove();

 } // end our conditional statement
 }); //close our loop of values

 //Get the charts
 var defaultSlides=slides.getSlides();
 var defaultSlide = defaultSlides [1]
 var position = {right: 490, bottom: 190};
 var size = {height: 140, width: 230};
 defaultSlide.insertSheetsChart(
 chartRegion1,
 position.right,
 position.bottom,
 size.width,
 size.height);

 var defaultSlides=slides.getSlides();
 var defaultSlide = defaultSlides [1]
 var position = {right: 200, bottom: 190};
 var size = {height: 140, width: 230};
 defaultSlide.insertSheetsChart(
 chartGender1,
 position.right,
 position.bottom,
 size.width,
 size.height);


 // Create and display a dialog telling the user where to
 // find the new presentation.
 var slidesUrl = slides.getUrl();
 var html = "<p>Find it in your home Drive folder:</p>"
  + "<p><a href=\"" + slidesUrl + "\" target=\"_blank\">"
  + presentationTitle + "</a></p>";

 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(
 HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  .setHeight(120)
  .setWidth(350),
  "Report Generated!"
  );
  }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243345/discussion-on-question-by-kikuchi-how-to-remove-google-sheets-chart-from-google).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- You have Google Slides including some charts.
- When the chart is "No data", you want to remove the chart from the Google Slides.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.
- From your sample Spreadsheet including the sample "No data" chart, your "No data" chart has no values.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Google Spreadsheet including the charts. And, please set the Google Slides ID to `presentationId`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const presentationId = "###"; // Please set the Google Slides ID.

  // 1. Retrieve the charts with "No data".
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const obj = ss.getSheets().reduce((o, sheet) => {
    sheet.getCharts().forEach(chart => {
      const check = chart.getRanges().some(e => {
        const temp = e.getDisplayValues();
        return temp[0].map((_, c) => temp.map(r => r[c])).some(col => col.join("") == "");
      });
      if (check) o[chart.getChartId()] = check;
    });
    return o;
  }, {});

  // 2. Remove the charts with "No data".
  const slides = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId).getSlides();
  slides.forEach(slide => {
    slide.getSheetsCharts().forEach(chart => {
      if (obj[chart.getChartId()]) chart.remove();
    });
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, first, the charts of "No data" are retrieved in an object. And, using this object, the charts in Google Slides are removed.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your sample Spreadsheet. If the condition of "No data" is changed, this script might not be able to be used. So, please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [remove() of Class SheetsChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/sheets-chart#remove)

Comment: @Kikuchi Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Kikuchi As an important point, in my proposed script, it supposes that the chart on Google Slides links to the chart on Google Spreadsheet. Using this link, it checks whether the chart is "No data". When the chart on Slides doesn't link to the chart on Spreadsheet, this script cannot be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: The script is working exactly like I want it to work. When there is no data, it removes the chart. When there is data, it keeps the chart. Really thank you for this perfect script. I am very happy that you were able to solve my issue ^^

Comment: @Kikuchi Thank you for testing it again. I'm glad for it.

Comment: I sent you a small thank you on Paypal. Have a wonderful day and thank you again for your time and help ^^

Comment: @Kikuchi I appreciate it. I'm glad that my answer is useful for your situation. Thank you, too!

Comment: I hope you are doing well. I have a new question if you can please help with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71690163/how-to-replace-a-placeholder-in-google-slide-with-an-image-from-a-image-url-in-s

Comment: @Kikuchi About your new question, I answered it. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I confirmed it and it's working perfectly. Arigato Sensei! Really thank you for your time and ongoing support. You are saving me from time-consuming tasks at work. I sent you a small gift to thank you on Paypal. I wish you a great day!

Comment: @Kikuchi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new question was resolved.

Comment: Hello Tainaike how are you ? I am very sorry to bother you but the code is not working anymore. I tried everything with no luck...can you have a look and see what could be the problem ? Here's the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MBqnmS9pxgJOrsnZJtyVCDATy8qxoGxz78alWQiBAnI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry again to bother you but now it's working, it was not working because the values of the chart were coming from another sheet, I was copying the chart from somewhere else. So now I recreated the chart and its values inside the sheet and it's working. Thank you very much for this amazing piece of code 

Comment: @Kikuchi First, I deeply apologize for my late response. From your 2 comments, I understood that your new question was resolved. I'm glad for it.

Comment: I hope you are doing great! Arigato Sensei 

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your new question, it seems that the discussions have already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussions.