# Add charts inside a ForEach Loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have a script that creates a Google Slide for every Google Sheet Row. I would like to also embed a chart inside of each of those slides.

The forEachloop loops 5 slides. How can I tell the script to insert a chart on each of these slides but to change those charts on each loop ?

I have added the below code to my forEach loop, but it's adding all 5 charts on all the loops instead of adding 1 chart on each loop.

```
var genderposition = {right: 30, bottom: 105};
var gendersize = {height: 300, width: 380};
charts.forEach(c => newSlide2.insertSheetsChart(...c,
    genderposition.right,
    genderposition.bottom,
   gendersize.width,
   gendersize.height),
   );
```

So in other words, I want charts[0] to be added in the first loop, charts[1] to be added in the second loop, charts[2] to be added in the third loop, etc...

Here's my code.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Overall Performance 1');
  var templateId = "15q13aEt3MuHHnOnYyX6RE04bvnXk_B38qDWkowd5tzs";
  var template = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);
  var templatePres = SlidesApp.openById(templateId);
  var templateSlides = templatePres.getSlides();
  var fileName = ss.getName();
  var copy = template.makeCopy();
    copy.setName(fileName);
  var copyID = copy.getId();
  var slides = SlidesApp.openById(copyID);
  var defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();

     var campaignvalues = sheet.getRange('A3:J20').getValues(); 
     campaignvalues.forEach(function(page){
  if(page[0]){
    
   var landingPage = page[0];
   var reach = page[1];
   var impressions = page[2];
   var clicks = page[3];
   var ctr = page[4];
   var engagements = page[5];
   var engagementrate = page[6];
   var cpm = page[7];
   var cpr = page[8];
   var spent = page[9];
    var texts = [
      ["{{landing page}}", landingPage],
      ["{{reach}}", reach],
      ["{{impressions}}", impressions],
      ["{{clicks}}", clicks],
      ["{{ctr}}", ctr],
      ["{{engagements}}", engagements],
      ["{{engagementrate}}",engagementrate],
      ["{{cpm}}", cpm],
      ["{{cpr}}",cpr],
      ["{{spent}}", spent],
    ];



    // Insert slides from template
   var index = 0;
   templateSlides.forEach(function(slide) {
     var newSlide = slides.insertSlide(index);
     var elements = slide.getPageElements();
     elements.forEach(function(element) {
       newSlide.insertPageElement(element);
    });
   index++;
   });

   defaultSlides = slides.getSlides();
   var newSlide2 = defaultSlides[1];
   var newSlide3 = defaultSlides [2];
   var newSlide4 = defaultSlides [3];
   var newSlide5 = defaultSlides [4];
   var newSlide6 = defaultSlides [5];


    texts.forEach(t => newSlide2.replaceAllText(...t));
    //if (!imageUrl) return;
var charts = [
  [sheet.getCharts()[1]],
  [sheet.getCharts()[25]],
  [sheet.getCharts()[50]],
  [sheet.getCharts()[75]],
  [sheet.getCharts()[100]],
  ];

var genderposition = {right: 30, bottom: 105};
var gendersize = {height: 300, width: 380};
charts.forEach(c => newSlide2.insertSheetsChart(...c,
    genderposition.right,
    genderposition.bottom,
   gendersize.width,
   gendersize.height),
   );

   var presLength = defaultSlides.length; 
   newSlide2.move(presLength);
   newSlide3.move(presLength);
   newSlide4.move(presLength);
   newSlide5.move(presLength);
   newSlide6.move(presLength);
   defaultSlides[0].remove();
   defaultSlides[6].remove();
   

  } // end our conditional statement
  }); //close our loop of values

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: On your code, we do not know the values/structure of `campaignvalues` **array variable** thus, it would very difficult to replicate it, as discussed on the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) documentation.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. Thank you for your response. I will add the values of campaignvalues

Comment: @IrvinJayG. I have added the variables. Thank you again for taking your time to look at my script.

Comment: @Kikuchi thanks for adding additional details but your code is still incomplete. It is unclear what is the structure of `templateSlides` on the code line  `templateSlides.forEach(function (slide) {...`. Also, inside that looping I get an error `ReferenceError: slides is not defined` on the line with `var newSlide = slides.insertSlide(index);`. What is the structure of the variable `slides`?

Comment: @IrvinJayG. Thank you again for your response. I will add all the abovementioned variables.

Comment: @Kikuchi Additionally, kindly double check the part of your code that you're sharing & make sure it is reproducible (it runs on your end without any errors) even when using a sample spreadsheet file _(with test data inside it)_ and a **sample empty Google Slides** file. That way, the community can investigate the issues with your looping logic.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. I have added the additional variables. Also, I have checked the code from my end and it runs without any errors. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247166/discussion-between-irvin-jay-g-and-kikuchi).

Comment: About your comment of `The chat discussions have stopped since an hour, and with no solution. Could you please have a look at my question now ?` to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71628227), in this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that the user is thinking of a solution. So, how about waiting for the user's next response?

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION

Based on your question, here are your goals:

1. Get all charts from a specific sheet tab
2. Define which charts you'll be placing to your slide file by adding identifiers on each slide, e.g. **{{chart}}**
3. Place the charts via a looping method based on chart identifiers

- ***Some limitations found in your current code***

> It seems it is not possible to simply use the [*replaceAllText()*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#replacealltextfindtext,-replacetextf) method when placing the Google Sheet charts on every Google Slide, as this can only replace **text** values. This would mean that you would need to manually define the position *(`Left` & `Top`)* of every sheet chart on each of your slides *(I have added an implementation on the code below where you could to define the position of every chart)*.

Below is a sample function called `placeCharts(sheetname, slidesID, chartsIndexesToCopy)` where you can add to existing your code & then run it inside your main function with these parameters:

- **`sheetname`**
  The Sheet Tab Name
- **`slidesID`**
  The Google Slides ID
- **`chartsIndexesToCopy`**
  The array of Chart Indexes you want to be copied

### *Apps Script Function*

```
function placeCharts(sheetname, slidesID, chartsIndexesToCopy) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var remainingIndex = 0;
  var gendersize = { height: 300, width: 280 };
  var slides = SlidesApp.openById(slidesID).getSlides();
  var definedPos;

  //Define Left & Top Position per specifc {{chart}} identifier here:
  //E.g. Define positions for {{chart}} & {{chart2}}
  var position = [{ chart: '{{chart}}', left: 50, top: 120 },
                  { chart: '{{chart2}}', left: 380, top: 120 }];

  slides.forEach((_, index) => {
    try {
      var currentSlide = slides[index + 1].getShapes();
      currentSlide.forEach(x => {
        if (x.getText().asString().trim().match(/chart/g)) {

          //When a chart has no position defined, it will auto set to default Left and Top positions [[30, 105]]
          definedPos = position.map(pos => { return pos.chart === x.getText().asString().trim() ? [pos.left, pos.top] : null }).filter(y => y);
          definedPos.length == 0 ? definedPos = [[30, 105]] : definedPos;

          //Paste sheet charts on every slides that contains any textboxes with the word "chart"
          slides[index + 1].insertSheetsChart(
            charts[chartsIndexesToCopy[remainingIndex]],
            definedPos[0][0],
            definedPos[0][1],
            gendersize.width,
            gendersize.height
          )

          //Logs for review
          console.log(chartsIndexesToCopy[remainingIndex] == undefined ?
            "Variable \"chartsIndexesToCopy\" length doesn't contain the dedicated chart index number for the " + x.getText().asString().trim() + " on slide #" + (index + 1) : "Found \"" + x.getText().asString().trim() + "\" on slide #" + (index + 1) + "\nChart index #" + chartsIndexesToCopy[remainingIndex] + " has been pasted on slide #" + (index + 1));
          console.log("Position for " + x.getText().asString().trim() + " :\nLEFT: " + definedPos[0][0] + "\nTOP: " + definedPos[0][1])
          remainingIndex = remainingIndex + 1;
          x.getText().replaceAllText(x.getText().asString().trim(), '');//remove the text indetifier after placing chart
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
    }
  })
}
```

### ***Demonstration***

- Run the `placeCharts` on a main test function as seen below. In the sample, it will be copying 5 charts (1, 25, 50, 75, 100) from your spreadsheet file tab named `Copy of Overall Performance 1` to your destination slide file:

> [image]

- The Google Slides (e.g. Slides with **{{chart}}** & **{{chart2}}** identifiers) after running the function:

> [image]

- Other charts have also been placed on every slide with identifiers

> [image]

- The execution log results for review:

> [image]

### NOTE:

- On the demonstration, I only made a specific position for the identifiers **{{chart}}** & **{{chart2}}**, thus, others were misaligned when got pasted & you'll need to define the rest yourself on the code, as seen here:

> [image]

- Chart indexes defined will be applied in order & incrementally based on the order of chart text box identifiers you have placed on every slide.

> In theory, with these chart indexes `[1, 25, 50, 75, 100]` you have defined, `1` will replace **{{chart}}** and `25` will replace **{{chart2}}** and on & so forth.

### ***Resources***

- [replaceAllText(findText, replaceText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide?hl=en#replacealltextfindtext,-replacetext)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However there is a misunderstanding. I do not want to replace all the placeholders with the charts. I want each of those 5 charts to be place on every loop of slide 2. Or I want to replace the placeholder {{chart}} with one of those charts on each loop. So first loop of slide, {{chart}} will be replaced by first chart, second loop of slide, {{chart}} will be replaced by second chart. Etc .. I apologize that the placeholders confused you.

Comment: Honestly, it quite hard to grasp what you mean with _"I want each of those 5 charts to be place on every loop of slide 2. Or I want to replace the placeholder {{chart}} with one of those charts on each loop. So first loop of slide, {{chart}} will be replaced by first chart, second loop of slide, {{chart}} will be replaced by second chart."_

Comment: In reality, do you only need to loop through Slide 2, correct?

Comment: Is your goal to appear all 5 charts on the `{{chart}}` placeholder one at a time via looping? Almost like a slide animation?

Comment: Yes this is correct one at a time via looping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247170/discussion-between-irvin-jay-g-and-kikuchi).